# Evaluating dockerfile args in mvn commands

Tags: java, maven, docker, dockerfile

How to use dockerfile args in maven commands?

Current approach:

---

Dockerfile

```
ARG PARAM=value
...
RUN /mvnw package -DParam=$PARAM
...
```

The problem with this approach is the arguments passed to mvn command aren't interpolated. What's the possible workaround?

Comment: You could try `RUN /mvnw package -DParam=${PARAM}`. Also could you show how you are setting this build arg during image build?

Comment: Gave it a try before - ``${param}`` doesn't work too. The arg has default vaule - value, when the image is being built the ``/mvnw package -DParam=$PARAM`` is executed  instead of ``/mvnw package -DParam=value``

Comment: did you try with `ARG PARAM=value
ENV PARAM=$PARAM
RUN /mvnw package -DParam=$PARAM` or `ENV PARAM=test`? but args should work, did you pass value to ARG?